# Determine if a process is running?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, process

Is there an easy way to determine if a certain process is running?
I need to know if an instance of my program is running in the background, and if not fork and create the background process.

Answer (score 5):

Normally the race-free way of doing this is:

- Open a lock file / pid file for writing (but do not truncate it)
- Attempt to take an exclusive lock on it (using fcntl or flock) without blocking
- If that fails with EAGAIN, then the other process is already running.
- The file descriptor should now be inherited by the daemon and left open for its lifetime

The advantage of doing this over simply storing a PID, is that if somebody reuses the PID, you won't get a false positive.

The biggest problem with storing the pid in the file is that a low-numbered pid used by a system start up daemon can get reused on a subsequent reboot by a different daemon. I have seen this happen.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done using pidfiles: a file in /var/run/[name].pid containing only the process ID returned by fork().

```
if pidfile exists:
  exit()
else:
  create pidfile
  pid = start_background()
  pidfile.write(pid)

On shutdown: remove pidfile
```

Comment: I don't see many pid files in that folder, much is missing. Is there somewhere else?

Comment: That's where system pidfiles are supposed to be put according to the [FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/2.2/fhs-5.13.html).

If you're writing a user-level program, you can put the pidfile in the user's home directory (~/.[name]/[name].pid).

Comment: Very likely--little in standard C I/O is defined to be atomic, so that's pretty hard to avoid.  Create the pidfile before spawning the background process and guard for cleanup, and I think risk should be fairly negligible.

Comment: Notice that `if pidfile exists` will trigger also for old stale pid files. You might also want to examine the content of the pid file and at least verify that the process is alive, possibly also checking the name of the process.

Answer (score 0):

Linux software, by far and large *does not care* about the exclusivity of programs, only the resources they use. "Caring" is most often provided by the implementation (E.G. the infrastructure of the distro).

For instance, if you want to run a program, but that program locks up or turns zombie and you have no way to kill it, or it's running as a different user performing some other function. Why should the program care whether another copy of itself is running? Having it do so only seems like an unnecessary restriction.

If it's a process that opens a socket (like a TCP port), have the program fail if it can't open the socket. If it needs exclusive access to a file, have it fail if it can't get it. Support a PID file, but don't make it mandatory.

You'll see this methodology all over GNU software, which is part of what makes it so versatile.